# What is taking up all this space on my hardly-used tablet?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, disk-space

I have a tablet that I got about 2 years ago, but never opened it until recently (it was a package deal, and my laptop finally died).  When I booted it up, it went through a whole bunch of automatic updates, which makes sense.  It eventually ended up running Windows 10 (this may have been one of the automatic updates).

What doesn't make sense is that Windows Explorer shows less than 2GB of free space out of 28.5GB on my C drive.  This makes it virtually impossible to install any new software.  I tried running disk cleanup and removing all programs that I had no use for, but this hardly put a dent in the used space.

Visible folders show nothing unusual.  There is both a Windows package and a Windows10Upgrade package, but the latter doesn't seem to be taking up excessive space.  Other than that there's just the Program Files and Program Files (x86), Users, and a small number of my own files that don't take up much room.

My only guess is that all of the upgrades left some sort of garbage behind (maybe copies of earlier Windows versions or something?), but I can't figure out where it's being stored or how to get rid of it.

Comment: If there was an upgrade (as opposed to _update_), then there may be a `Windows.old` directory which allows you to revert to the previous release, and this could be occupying a large proportion of your free space: this should be removable in clean-up. That said, modern Win10 installations can easily take 25GB or more, even without `Windows.old`. You may be able to move your personal files to a permanently-mounted micro-SD if you have a slot, but beware that this will be less reliable than the internal disc, so make sure you have a frequent back-up regime.

Comment: Once you determine what is using your disk space, feel free to edit your question, and ask how you can reclaim that disk space.  Unless you edit your question then it’s a duplicate.